# xmgrace: customization of overlapped 2D plots

Tags: xmgrace

i am using the following gracebat command with multiple images

```
gracebat images*.png -legend load -batch combo.bfile -printfile RMSD.BAK.png -hardcopy
```

with the following batch script

```
HARDCOPY DEVICE \"PNG\"
PAGE SIZE 2560, 2048
xaxis tick major grid on
yaxis tick major grid on
xaxis tick major color \"grey\"
yaxis tick major color \"grey\"
xaxis tick major linewidth 2
yaxis tick major linewidth 2
xaxis tick major linestyle 2
yaxis tick major linestyle 2
xaxis label char size 2.2
yaxis label char size 2.2
xaxis ticklabel char size 2.0
yaxis ticklabel char size 2.0
```

to produce the images in the following format:
[image]

How could I customize (mainly via some options in the batch file) the legend added to the graph ?
Is it possible to change the style of ALL LINES at once (mainly the line width as well as color palette of each graph) ?